# 4 products on the same line in the template

Tags: html, css, django

I'm developing an e-commerce with Django. My backend is fine, my problem is with the template. Currently, I want to display 4 products per row, and if there are 7 products, the other 3 must be aligned with the top one. I'm using bootstrap to do this, however, for some reason I don't know, it doesn't have 4 products on the same line, even with space. I'm using a container with 1200px.

home.html

```
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row">
  
  <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div class="row">
        {% for product in products %}
        <div class="card mb-4 border rounded" style="width: 13.5rem;">
          <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
          {%if product.image %}
            <img class="img-produto" src='/media/{{product.image}}' class="card-img-top hover_img ">
          {% else%}
            <img class="img-produto" src="{% static '/img/not-found-product.jpg' %}" class="card-img-top hover_img">
          {%endif%}
          </a>
        
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-title">{{product.name}}</p>
          <p class="card-text"><i class='fas fa-dollar-sign' style="margin-right:2px"></i>{{product.price}}</p>
        </div>
        
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I certainly wouldn't have `width: 13.5rem;` in there.

Comment: @Paulie_D So, as I'm using django tags, it wasn't pleasant to use Stack Snippers

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `width: 13.5rem;` and add class [`col-4`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/) in the div. Like,

```html
<div class="col-4 card mb-4 border rounded">
  <!-- your content goes here -->
</div>
```

Comment: I managed to solve my problem. Reviewing the bootstrap documentation, on grid system. I found the answer. Rmoved <div class="col-lg-8">, <div class="row"> and added inside the for <div class="col-lg-3">